# Swiss may cancel my flight to Copenhagen. I have already paid for the non-refundable hotel room

Tags: switzerland, copenhagen, swiss

Swiss airline has laid off a lot of staff during COVID. Now they lack staff and cancel lots of flights.

I have a flight to Copenhagen at the end of the month. I have already paid for the hotel (before COVID) and it is non-refundable.

What do I do if the flight to Copenhagen is cancelled? Then I can not be in the non-refundable hotel and lose a lot of money.

Update:
Conversation with Swiss chat bot.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried emailing the hotel? Maybe due to the special circumstance they can make some provision for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they do cancel the flight, they will probably suggest to move you to a different flight (with the option of cancelling if that does not suit you) rather than just cancel without any options.

If they don't, or if the options they suggest do not match your needs, get the refund, and book a different flight.

If no flights suit you (or they are too expensive), you may consider the train, though it's quite long to get to Copenhagen from Switzerland.

If all else fails and you can't/won't go at all, check if the hotel doesn't still have Covid-related policies which actually let you cancel or change your booking.

The last resort would be to use any travel insurance you may have, either explicitly (bought separately or at the time you booked either the flight or the hotel) or implicitly (as part of the services of your credit card for instance).

Depending on when they cancel the flight/your ticket (if they do), you **may** be eligible for compensation of 250 €, though they will probably try to argue that these are somehow extraordinary circumstances.

Comment: @Josefine Not necessarily. It just means that at this time, everything is normal, but some airlines which have had lots of issues recently have cancelled flights very close to the flight date. So it may still happen that they cancel. But from what I can read, at the moment the planned cancellations only affect flights to Germany, Poland, Austria, the UK and LAX. I would think you are rather on the safe side, I'm not aware of any Swiss airport or CPH being subject to AMS-like meltdowns, and Swiss seem to be slightly proactive in their cancellations, but these days anything goes.